# SCP used with find anc -ctime in expect script does not work

Tags: bash, scripting, find, expect, scp

I already posted similar question before and got some help and I changed it to that but still it does not work.  I am trying to scp to a remote location and fetch latest files from a day back. It works when i run the command by itself.

This is how the script looks like:

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
exp_internal 1
set host_ip [lindex $argv 0 ]
set user [lindex $argv 1 ]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
set scp_remote_directory [lindex $argv 3 ]
set local_directory [lindex $argv 4]

set force_conservative 1  ;# set to 1 to force conservative mode even if
                          ;# script was not run conservatively originally
if {$force_conservative} {
        set send_slow {1 .1}
        proc send {ignore arg} {
                sleep .1
                exp_send -s -- $arg
        }
}

set timeout -1
#spawn scp $user@$host_ip:$scp_remote_directory/$scp_remote_filename $local_directory/
#spawn rsync -azv $user@$host_ip:\´\$(find\ $scp_remote_directory\ -ctime\ -1\ )\´ $local_directory/
#spawn scp $user@$host_ip:\'\$(find\ $scp_remote_directory\ -ctime\ -1)\' $local_directory/
spawn scp $user@$host_ip:\`\$(find\ $scp_remote_directory\ -ctime\ -1\ )\` $local_directory/
#spawn scp $user@$host_ip:$scp_remote_directory/CscfHealthCheckReport_$TagID_$phase* $local_directory/
match_max 100000
expect {
  -exact "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? " {
    send -- "yes\r"
    exp_continue
  }
  -exact "${user}@${host_ip}'s password: " {
    send -- "$password\r"
  }
  -exact "Password: " {
    send -- "$password\r"
  }
}
expect eof
```

It complains on permissions but it is not a permissions issue. If i change in the SCP line ` to ' i get another issue.

here is the printout:

```
/td_general_scp.exp 10.33.122.22 root rootroot /cluster/storage/no-backup/coremw/var/log/saflog/FaultManagementLog/alarm/Fm*.log /home/imstest/shared/Generate/ReportingT3/tmp
spawn scp root@10.33.122.22:`$(find /cluster/storage/no-backup/coremw/var/log/saflog/FaultManagementLog/alarm/Fm*.log -ctime -1 )` /home/imstest/shared/Generate/ReportingT3/tmp/
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {141218}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match exact string "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? "? no
"root@10.33.122.22's password: "? no
"Password: "? no
Password: 
expect: does "Password: " (spawn_id exp6) match exact string "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? "? no
"root@10.33.122.22's password: "? no
"Password: "? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Password: "
send: sending "rootroot\r" to { exp6 }

bash: /cluster/storage/no-backup/coremw/var/log/saflog/FaultManagementLog/alarm/FmAlarmLog_20160422_152507_20160426_135452.log: Permission denied
expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\nbash: /cluster/storage/no-backup/coremw/var/log/saflog/FaultManagementLog/alarm/FmAlarmLog_20160422_152507_20160426_135452.log: Permission denied\r\n"
```

The name of the script is td_general_scp.exp

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The remote shell executes `$(find ...)` and emits file names. That's find.

But you surround that in backticks, so you are now attempting to *execute* the find output as a script.

You probably want to step away from scp and use rsync instead.

Comment: Hi Glenn, thanks for the input but I tried rsync aswell. I had a similar question regarding that in this link. Same type of error check it out.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785164/using-rsync-in-expect-script-with-find-ctime-give-me-an-error)          I surrounded it with ticks because I got that suggestion on that question.